# Android Check Availability of Remote Server/ Check if the remote server alive?

Tags: php, android

I am building an android application, which takes input argument as IPADDRESS, I have to check if the remote server is available or not?

Basically I am trying to reach http://serverip/request.php

But I want to check if the server is alive and then proceed with my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a AsyncTask which pings the server and based on the response proceed.

Use the class HttpURLConnection

```
doInBackground(..) {
    boolean success = false;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"OpenConnection call failed");
    }
        success = true;
    }
    return success;
}
```

Comment: Above code gives the `true` only, if url ="http://www.unavailablereally.com/" or url = "http://www.android.com/". If we have any changes like "hp:" instead of "http" it throws exception. How can we find that if "http://www.google.com/" means available and if "http://www.unavailablereally.com/" means Server unavailable results...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a servlet/webpages or whatever you feel comfortable on the server that return ok or error depending on server status from your android you must call that URL and check returned value, also on your try/catch you must watch specific exception for example related with timeout, also check for http status if your http request returned 200 then was ok and you can fetch server status from that URL Check http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

```
        `boolean isOK = false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://yourserverurl/yourstatusmethod");
            HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlcon.connect();
            if (urlcon.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                    String serverStatus = readStream(in); //assuming that "http://yourserverurl/yourstatusmethod" returns OK or ERROR depending on your server status check         
                    isOK = (serverStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("OK"));
            }else{
              isOK = false;
            }

            url.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                    isOK = false;
                    e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    isOK = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
        }

    the readStream is a method that convert inputstream to string
    `public static String readStream (InputStream in) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] b = new byte[4096];
        for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
            out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }    return out.toString();
    }`

this is just and idea.... there are a lot of ways to check server availability
```